# MySQL query using $_GET with quotation marks

Tags: php, mysql, get

I am having trouble finding a syntax that works in this query to receive JSON data:

```
$info ='".mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET['clientlist'])."';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT clientname FROM `cms_client` WHERE clientname ='$info' ORDER BY clientname ASC");
```

When I put this in my browser: http://mydomain.com/myfile.php?clientname=Redbox

I get an empty response.

When I change my query to:

```
//$info ='".mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET['clientlist'])."';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT clientname FROM `cms_client` WHERE clientname ='Redbox' ORDER BY clientname ASC");
```

When I put this in my browser: http://mydomain.com/myfile.php

The database responds with "Redbox"

Could someone please help me with the correct syntax?

Comment: Correct syntax for what? Your second code is syntactically correct (though the query makes no sense). Explain what quotes in your first code are for.

Comment: why wouldn't it display Redbox? You're display `clientname` and filtering down to where `clientname` is Redbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to:

```
$info = mysql_real_escape_string ($_GET['clientlist']);
```

Else you have double quotation marks in your query.

And the url must be `http://mydomain.com/myfile.php?clientlist=Redbox` and not `?clientname=`

Comment: Thank you redreggae, examples elsewhere in this forum lead me into using the quotes and periods. and me typing clientname instead of clientlist I will attribute to being up too many hours.